# How can I persist last modified date of image file on android?

Tags: android

I`m developing an android app which compresses all images on phone.

I used Content Resolver to handle images. But, Last modified date of images was changed after compressing. I want to keep the date because the order of images are changed after media scan (after reboot).

- Updating ContentValues on images using Content Resolver didn`t work because Last modified date of images was rebuilded after media scan.
- Call "File.setLastModified()" also could be unable to work because validity of this method depends on setup of SD card.

I need persistent method to keep the last modified date after media scan. I assume that Content Resolver can provide the method persisting properties.

Would you help me?

Comment: Maybe you can use EXIF info if your file are images, [this tuto](http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2009/12/read-exif-information-in-jpeg-file.html) could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying EXIF info is worked! Thank you!
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

```
ExifInterface exif=new ExifInterface(path);    
ExifInterface exifNew=new ExifInterface(newPath);
exifNew.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME));
exifNew.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
exifNew.saveAttributes();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this logic will help you out.

```
try {
            InputStream is = new URL("your image url").openStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis,true);


    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
    for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
        System.out.println(tag);
    }
 }

            }
        catch (ImageProcessingException e){}
        catch (IOException e) {}
```

This is snipped code which we can able get created date, last modified date etc.,

Comment: Metadata class you've wrote doesn't support setting of EXIF property. But I appreciate it!